# Detecting Escape presses on open select lists in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am writing an interface where when Escape is pressed it triggers the cancel button, if there is one.  But I do not want to interfere with the standard logic that if a `select` drop down list is open that Escape will close the list.  If a `select` element just happens to have focus though then the interface should be cancelled.

In Chrome and Opera no events are triggered by pressing Escape when a `select` list is open, so everything works as expected by default.

In Safari there is a `keyup` event but no preceding `keydown` one in this context.  I have been able to resolve by setting a flag on `keydown` that I can then check for on `keyup`.

```
var _menuEscapeState = false
    ,_menu = document.getElementById( 'menu' );

_menu.addEventListener( 'keydown' ,function( e ) {
    var e = e || window.event;
    _menuEscapeState = ( e.which === 27 );
} );

_menu.addEventListener( 'keyup' ,function( e ) {
    var e = e || window.event;
    if( e.which === 27 && _menuEscapeState ) {
        // DO STUFF
    }
    _menuEscapeState = false;
} );
```

But in Firefox it seems both a `keyup` and `keydown` fire when closing a `select` list.  So is there any way to detect whether the list is open to be able to filter this out?  Or is the only option to detect the use of Firefox and simply disable the Escape-to-cancel functionality in this browser?

Incidentally, I do not have IE to test with which is why it is not mentioned at this time, although the site is primarily aimed at use on a Mac.